# String.split won't split with \n when reading a string from a file

Tags: java, string

This is on Windows. It worked when I had the \n in a string I created in the class but it doesn't when reading the same string from a file.

```
String[] string = str.split(" \\n| |\\n|\n");
```

Example of string in file:

> This is a test.\nColor: [blue yellow black green red]\nDates:

If the code I use to read from the file is of any relavalence:

```
public static String getStringArray(String filename) {
        try {
            return IOUtils.toString(new FileInputStream(filename), Charset.defaultCharset());
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(File.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This is using org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.

Comment: Have you tried `\r\n`? This is a new line in Windows. You can write new lines with `\n` but you can't necessarily read them in the same way.

Comment: @Zircon Just tried it and still doesn't split.
str.split("\\r\\n| \\n| |\\n");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, a method called `getStringArray` should return `String[]`, not `String`.

Also, the regex "(\\n|\r?\n)" does what you expect (according to my understanding).

It breaks the lines either by literal "\n" or by line-breaks.

```
public static String[] getStringArray(String filename)
{
    try
    {
        String content = IOUtils.toString(new FileInputStream(filename), Charset.defaultCharset());
        String[] lines = content.split("(\\\\n|\\r?\\n)");
        return lines;
    } catch (IOException ex)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(File.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Or, in a reduced way:

```
public static String[] getStringArray(String filename)
{
    try { return IOUtils.toString(new FileInputStream(filename), Charset.defaultCharset()).split("(\\\\n|\\r?\\n)"); }
    catch (IOException ex) { Logger.getLogger(File.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex); }
    return null;
}
```

If you iterate over the returned array (using your sample string), you will get:

> This is a test.
>
> Color: [blue yellow black green red]
>
> Dates:

Answer (score 0):

Use the "line ending" expression `\R` (introduced in Java 8).

It seems you want to split on spaces or line endings, ie:

```
str.split("[ \R]+")
```